# Set value of a TextBox in View from a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an `input` box in a `View` and i am trying to pass value from my controller.
Value is perfectly getting in line   `ViewBag.request_number = final`, but in my  view it is displaying `null`

```
public JobsController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        string prefix = "D";
        string lastPRNo = "D0001";
        string number = lastPRNo;
        if (lastPRNo.Length < 3)
        {
            number = "000" + lastPRNo;
            number = number.Substring(number.Length - 3, 3);
        }
        string final = prefix + number;
        ViewBag.request_number = final;
        _context = context;
    }
```

My `View` code is below.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <label asp-for="JobNumber" class="control-label"></label>
  <input id="JobNumber" asp-for="JobNumber" value=@ViewBag.request_number class="form-control" type="text" />
  <span asp-validation-for="JobNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try moving the code of getting Request Number to

```
public IActionResult YourView()  
    {
    string prefix = "D";
    string lastPRNo = "D0001";
    string number = lastPRNo;
    if (lastPRNo.Length < 3)
    {
        number = "000" + lastPRNo;
        number = number.Substring(number.Length - 3, 3);
    }
    string final = prefix + number;
    ViewBag.request_number = final;
    _context = context;   }
```

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag has a dependency on ViewData and ViewData is populated after the controller is initialized.

This makes impossible to set ViewBag in the constructorbecause when the Controller's constructor is called, the properties for HttpContext, ControllerContext etc. are not set. They are only set after the constructor is called and there is a valid instance/reference to this object.

As you can read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/918d953767a8a9988c9e075254b70866e8b24e76/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Controller.cs)

ViewBag code looks like this:

```
public dynamic ViewBag
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_viewBag == null)
                    {
                        _viewBag = new DynamicViewData(() => ViewData);
                    }
    
                    return _viewBag;
                }
            }
```

And in the ViewData property you can see this:

> This property can be accessed after the controller has been activated,
> for example, in a controller action or by overriding OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)